# Unable to start the virtual device Details: failed to create framebuffer image (error: 15)

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

Unable to start the virtul device

To start virtual devices, make sure that your video card supports OpenGL2.0 and update the drivers.

Details: failed to create framebuffer image (error: 15)
If possible, update your video card drivers

Answer (score 2):

do you attemp to run genymotion via rdp on windows virtual machine? 3d Acceleration on Windows work only when you use physical console, sorry for my english.

Comment: Thank you , I install video card drivers. Genymotion can useable.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to figure the problem out.

1. delete Genymotion / VM Virtual Device / Graphic driver(mine is intel) and reboot
2. install newest version of graphic driver
3. install genymotion(without VM virtual device)
4. download and install the newest version of VM virtual device
5. manually start the device on VM virtual device
6. start the device on genymotion

Wish this work to y'all as well