# Genymotion failed to create framebuffer image,not getting any workable solution

Tags: android, virtual, genymotion

Hello Developers,

I spent my continuous effort to solve Genymotion errors i was getting on my window vista based system.I followed all the available questions and there solutions but nothing works in my favor.Here i am adding the error details which i am getting-

- Very First i was getting the No ip address found for device .i updated my genymotion and virtual machine so that is solved.
- Now i am getting error unable to start virtual device.**Failed to create frame buffer.Make sure that your video card support open gl 2.0,update driver.**

Tried -

- Updated driver from intel site ,no effect after that too.
- Updated genymotion latest i am using,Jdk everything,Virtual machine

Sorry Due to new bees here i am not able to upload images .I will update once i get atleast 10 reputation thats minimum requirement.
Please guys provide my solution.Almost two full day i am continuously trying please guys provide me solutions.

Comment: Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31111651/unable-to-start-the-virtual-device-details-failed-to-create-framebuffer-image?newreg=c198ed967033499cbb7347cc5eecb082

Comment: Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795787/genymotion-virtual-device-opengl-error?rq=1

Comment: +1. I also have same problem. can't solved yet. Jeff could you give me the solution if you already have done?

Answer (score 6):

this same thing happened to me. I found [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c8295ef8-3711-4576-9293-2c4965280165/opengl-and-remote-desktop) link which explains that starting an Open GL 2.0 software application (Genymotion emulator) over Microsoft RDP will cause the software to run on the client machine, not the host. I requested my boss to login to the physical machine, launch the emulator, and then log out so I can RDP back in, sure enough my emulator was running and accessible. I have found also that using TeamViewer will not give this error, so perhaps if no one is able to access your physical computer, you can start the emulator through TeamViewer and revert back to RDP as needed. Best of luck with this, it was very frustrating to me as well!